# blur background image of div?

Tags: css

i have a div which contains my background image and the background image is set to cover 100% width and height of the page. I'm blurring my image slightly.

The problem  get is I end up with a white space around the edge of my page?

Andy idea's where I'm going wrong? thanks

css:

```
#background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('../images/drop.png');
    background-size: cover;
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  -moz-filter: blur(2px);
  -o-filter: blur(2px);
  -ms-filter: blur(2px);
  filter: blur(2px);

}

body {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #333331;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="background"></div>
```

Comment: A [**Demo**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be usedul.

Comment: Cannot reproduce - http://jsfiddle.net/933342rz/1/

Comment: Which browser? Can you post a screen shot showing the issue? Is that the full content of your HTML/CSS? Please read the link provided by @Paulie_D.

Answer (score 3):

If you are speaking about a gradient to white on image edges, this is how the blur works.

You can remedy that by spreading the image slightly outside the window, e.g.:

```
{
    ...
    position: fixed;
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    bottom: -10px;
}
```

to hide those white clearings outside the viewport edges.

Comment: Now it leaves white space at right and bottom edges. updating it with `-2px;` reduces the effect but still it persists.

Comment: @Giri it would be easier to work on some example ;) I've forked the code provided by @Paulie_D and updated it with my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/nyr4z5pp/ It seems to look allright. Are you sure you didn't leave `width` and `height` parameteres there somewhere?

Comment: ya you are right, removing `width` and `height` parameters worked.

Comment: @Giri good to hear. Don't forget to accept the answer if you are satisfied with it ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The white feathering effect occurs because the image needs to be larger than the container. You don't however need to use position fixed with negative margins or even a background div, it's better to use a simple `transform: scale(1.1);` with a pseudo element.

```
body {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body:after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('../images/drop.png');
  background-size: cover;
  filter: blur(2px);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
body .the-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```